# Upload YouTube Video on users behalf using Passport's Google Authentication using nodejs

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, passport.js

How do I make requests to the YouTube API (uploading a YouTube video) with a logged in Google User (using Passport's Google Auth)?

The Google API docs only show a way in which you have a pre-setup .json File with your personal credentials - I want users to log into my service and upload Videos onto YouTube via my NodeJS server, how would I handle this?

Thank you for any hints/tips/answers!

Comment: That's not possible. For to upload videos to YouTube through the Data API, you must be [properly authorized](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#auth), i.e. you should have successfully completed an OAuth 2.0 authentication/authorization flow.

Comment: Hi @stvar I've got an OAuth 2.0 Auth flow in place through Passport.js (http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth2) - Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: The official documentation is: [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps). There you'll find all the details w.r.t. refresh tokens, access tokens, and the intricacies of the authentication/authorization flow.